# Simple tool for creating 2d animations?

Tags: animation

This is a very basic question, but I would really appreciate any help, since I don't know anything about animations,
which makes googling for the answer quite difficult. I'm not a technical person, so I hope my explanations are not impossible to understand.

I am looking for a software tool with which I can create the following:

1) A ,,Graphic'' with very simple elements like boxes+labels, connecting arrows, circle shapes in 2d. (Like you could create in 
LibreOffice Draw, example as jpg here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/grundschuld.jpg/   ) Design or looks is not too important.

2) Out of this I want a simple way to create a ,,movie'' where actions occur sequentially like: Line turns red, Ball moves to ObjectB etc.
It would be great if one could create this in a drag and drop fashion, but I'm open to any suggestions.

3) Additionally it would be great if I could incorporate some simple ,,interactive'' elements like: If you click on ObjectA, it 
changes color.

The animations do not have to be for the web or any special platform, they just need to run on a Ubuntu11.04 desktop, if thats impossible WindowsXP
is fine too. Anything open-source or not too costly would be great.
In my search I found the ,,Processing'' language, which seemingly should be able to do everything I want, but it would be really great
if you could recommend me a simpler tool with a GUI!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Adobe Flash
http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-Flash-Professional-CS5-5/3000-6676_4-10018718.html